# Replying via email to recruiter SO message does not work

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs, email, jobs-messages

Yesterday I applied to a job on StackOverflow and then today received an email saying:

> [Company name] has sent you a reply:
>
> [...]
>
> You can respond to [Company name] by replying to this email or viewing the thread on Stack
> Overflow

I chose to reply via email.

But then I received this error response:

```
Mail Delivery Subsystem <mailer-daemon@googlemail.com>
12:52 PM (2 minutes ago)

Error Icon
Address not found
Your message wasn't delivered to notifications@stackoverflow.email because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail.
```

UPDATE: After seeing the first 3 comments (ending with [Replying via email to recruiter SO message does not work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401994/replying-via-email-to-recruiter-so-message-does-not-work?noredirect=1#comment801779_401994)), I decided to take a closer look.

I wonder if my Gmail isn't honoring the "reply-to" header of the email. I see that there is a unique "reply-to":

[image]

But then when I click the Reply button in Gmail, the recipient shows as:

[image]

Comment: Well, it's probably a no-reply email adress. There should be some other email adress to contact, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @10Rep If that's the case then it shouldn't say "You can respond to [Company name] by replying to this email..." Either there's a bug or the text is wrong.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery The bug is that the email is a no-reply, right?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I added screenshots above about the "reply-to".

Comment: I can confirm: your email client should be using the unique `reply-to` email address in order to reply to the message.  Which email client are you using?

Comment: The Gmail website in Win 10 Chrome.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't seem to reproduce this error. But, it seems to be an issue with GMail not respecting the reply-to email for your account.

Comment: Coincidentally, I just accepted that job offer. I'm glad I persisted when the original email bounced :-) And yeah I'm starting to suspect (as you are) that it was a glitch with Gmail rather than SO since we can clearly see the reply-to populated but then not used as the recipient for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the discussion in the comments, I'm unable to reproduce this behavior in GMail, but this seems to be an issue in GMail itself.  The email client *should* be respecting the `reply-to` email address provided in the email headers, but, as you pointed out in the question, that doesn't appear to be happening.  Instead, the reply is going to our `notifications` email, which indeed will bounce.